# How to tell if a string can be transformed into another string by removing or uppercasing lowercase letters?

Tags: perl

In perl, I have two input strings, for this example, `ahueFFggLKy` and `HFFGLK`. I want to be able to iterate through all of the possible combinations of my input without lowercase letter groups (`a`, `h`, `u`, `e`, `g`...`ah`, `au`...`hegy`, etc) so in each iteration lowercase letters are removed and the remaining lowercase letters are uppercased:

```
ah:
  ueFFggLKy                (UEFFGGLKY)
^^

au:
 h eFFggLKy                (HEFFGGLKY)
^ ^

hegy:
a u FF gLKy | a u FFg LKy  (AUFFGLKY)
 ^ ^  ^     |  ^ ^   ^

auegy:
 h  FF gLK  |  h  FFg LK    (HFFGLK)
^ ^^  ^   ^   ^ ^^   ^  ^    -^--^-
```

The last option (`auegy`) is the answer, and I want to be able to iterate over letters to determine if I am able to convert `ahueFFggLKy` to `HFFGLK` without modifying any of the capital letters. This example would return `"YES"`.

If inputs like `fOoBar` and `BAR` come up, I am not successfully able to convert `fOoBar` to `BAR` because the `O` in `fOoBar` is capitalized. My program would return `"NO"`.

Can someone provide me with a perl example of how this would be done?

Comment: Please show the Perl code that you are having problems with.

Comment: I cannot fathom what you mean. Your example doesn't correspond to any interpretation of *"all of the possible combinations"* of two strings that I know. Also, *"lowercase letters are removed and the remaining lowercase letters are uppercased"* doesn't make sense: once lower case letters have been removed there are none left to upper case.

Comment: Some lowercase letters are removed @Borodin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood your requirement: the first string may be transformed by either deleting or upper-casing any lower-case letter, and you wish to know whether the second string can be derived from the first in this way

I suggest that you can transform the second string to a regex pattern to achieve this. If every upper-case letter in the second string must be matched by the corresponding upper or lower-case letter in the first, with any number of intervening lower-case letters, then the transformation is possible. Otherwise it is not

This program implements the idea

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @pairs = (
    [ qw/ ahueFFggLKy HFFGLK / ],
    [ qw/ fOoBar      BAR    / ],
);

for my $pair ( @pairs ) {
    my ($s1, $s2) = @$pair;
    printf "%s => %s -- %s\n", $s1, $s2, contains($s1, $s2) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
}

sub contains {
    my ($s1, $s2) = @_;

    my $re = join ' \p{Ll}* ', map { "(?i: $_ )" } $s2 =~ /\p{Lu}/g;
    $re = qr/ ^ \p{Ll}* $re \p{Ll}* $ /x;

    $s1 =~ $re;
}
```

#### output

```
ahueFFggLKy => HFFGLK -- YES
fOoBar => BAR -- NO
```

---

To read an array like `@pairs` from STDIN you could write something like this

```
my @pairs;

{
    local $/;
    my @input = split ' ', <>;
    push @pairs, [ splice @input, 0, 2 ] while @input > 1;
}
```

Comment: How do I read the pairs from STDIN, with each word on a new line? `ahueFFggLKy` <newline> `HFFGLK`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of unelegant solution, but it seems to output what you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ all };

my ($str1, $str2) = qw( ahueFFggLKy HFFGLK );

my @small_indices;
push @small_indices, pos($str1) - 1 while $str1 =~ /[[:lower:]]/g;

my @present = (0) x @small_indices;
until (all { $_ } @present) {
    my $try = $str1;
    for my $i (reverse 0 .. $#present) {
        substr $try, $small_indices[$i], 1,
            $present[$i] ? substr $str1, $small_indices[$i], 1
                         : q();
    }

    if (uc $try eq $str2) {
        print $present[$_] ? q() : substr $str1, $small_indices[$_], 1
            for 0 .. $#present;
        print ":\n";

        my $j = 0;
        for my $i (0 .. length($str1) - 1) {
            my $char = substr $str1, $i, 1;
            if ($char eq uc $char || $present[$j++]) {
                print $char;
            } else {
                print '.';
            }
        }
        print "\n";
    }

    my $idx = 0;
    $present[$idx] = 0, ++$idx while $present[$idx];
    $present[$idx] = 1;
}
```

It builds an indicator function @present, which say what lowercase letters are present in the string. All possible values of @present are iterated by adding 1 to the binary number corresponding to the function.

Comment: Would you please explain the problem that you're solving?

Comment: This give me an error: `"all" is not exported by the List::Util module`

Comment: Upgrade your version of List::Util to 1.33 or higher.

Comment: @moo_we_all_do: Or remove the offending line and change the `all` call to `until (@present == grep $_, @present) {`